# Оператор function в javascript

Tags: javascript

Как можно заменить оператор `function` на `fn` или любое другое название в javascript?

Comment: Можно сделать fn(вашафункция), как сделать fn вашафунция() {} я не представляю. Мой вариант устроит?

Comment: и у этого вопроса +1?

Comment: function - это не оператор, это ключевое слово

Answer (score 3):

В первую очередь возникает вопрос **НАХРЕНА**? Вам что, лень писать слово function? Так пользуйтесь редакторами с автокомплитом.

Стандарт JavaScript не описывает способов замены своих ключевых слов на другие. Но в порядке бреда можно написать препроцессор JS-кода, который будет искать вхождения ваших ключевых слов и заменять их на ключевые слова стандартного JS. Стоит учесть, что тупая замена в тексте в этом случае не прокатит, нужны как минимум регулярки, а как максимум - лексический анализатор. Ведь будет неприятно, если препроцессор заменит имя переменной `defnum` на `defunctionum`.

Comment: В js есть анонимные фунции. Их можно передавать как параметры (калбеки) - не красиво как-то. Да и писать на нем много приходится.

Comment: Тогда вот вам ещё вариант - [CoffeeScript][1]. Это язык, компилируемый в JS, но с более лаконичным синтаксисом. В частности, анонимная функция будет выглядеть так:

    (x, y) -> x + y

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, операторы (var, function и пр.) нельзя заменить на другие.

Comment: Думаю АО думает по аналогии: если alert(txt) можно заменить на al(txt), то почему нельзя менять операторы?!

Comment: Ну вдруг есть способ. Представьте как здорово было б писать "fn" или "func". Тем более var сократили, а про function забыли.

Comment: Потому что alert — это функция, а function — это оператор. Операторы нельзя.

Comment: Есть объект Function. Может через него как-то?

Comment: Нет. Как написал человек ниже, только юзая свой предпроцессор.

Comment: А function это объект? Даже если это объект, то не тот. Это любая функция - экземпляр function. А оператор function, как и var, никак не может быть объектом

Comment: Через объект Function можно сделать так:

    var fn = new function(body) {
        return new Function(body);
    }

Теперь анонимную функцию можно создать так:

    fn('alert();')();

Только это не намного короче, да и с передачей параметров тот ещё геморрой. Придётся считывать их через переменную `arguments` по индексам. Вот так:

    fn('alert(arguments[0]);')('lol');

К тому же, тело функции будет представлять собой строку, что вообще не удобно.

Comment: Итоговая беда, так-сказать :), заключается в том, что в js нельзя создавать свои операторы, так ведь?!

P.s. а вообще есть языки, в которых операторы можно создавать?

Comment: А в каком языке можно? В некоторых можно перегружать существующие операторы (операторы, а не ключевые слова!), но перегружать и определять свои операторы и ключевые слова, насколько мне известно, нигде нельзя.

Comment: @fori1ton,  в FORTH можно :)

Answer (score 1):

Ха-ха, никак, смириться или написать свой препроцессор.

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript как уже сказано в других ответах нельзя заменить основные операторы. Но можно сделать частичную перегрузку арифметических операторов для изменения их поведения для собственных классов. Реализуется это методом перекрытия функции `toString`:

```
function MyClass(data)
{
    this.data = data;
}

var a = new MyClass("Hello ");
var b = new MyClass("world!");

console.log(a + b); // Вывод: [object Object][object Object]

MyClass.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.data;
}

console.log(a + b); // Вывод: Hello world!
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/cXk5t/

Как много от этого практической пользы сказать сложно..